# acts_as_votable ordering based on upvotes in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, each

I am using the acts_as_votable gem to order my links based on how many up-votes they get from users.

I used a .each iterator in my view originally to handle the ordering and it worked fine:

@links.order(cached_votes_up: :desc).each do |link|

But now I am trying to include the ordering functionality in my controller and it is not working. I tried a few different ways:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @links = Link.order(cached_votes_up: :desc)
    @links = Link.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)

    respond_to do |format| 
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
end

    class LinksController < ApplicationController
      before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

      def index
        @links = Link.order(cached_votes_up: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)

        respond_to do |format| 
          format.js
          format.html
        end
      end
end


class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @links = Link.order(cached_votes_up: :desc)
    @links.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)

    respond_to do |format| 
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

My _link partial:

```
<div class="link row clearfix">
    <h2>
      <%= image_tag link.avatar.thumb %>
    </h2>
    <h2>
      <%= link_to link.title, link %><br>
    </h2>
    <p>
      <%= link_to link.url, link %><br>
    </p>


<!-- acts_as_votable for like_link -->
    <div class="btn-group">
        <%= link_to like_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
          Upvote
          <%= link.get_upvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to dislike_link_path(link), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down">
          Downvote
          <%= link.get_downvotes.size %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div id="link"><%= render @links %></div>

<%= will_paginate @links %>
```

Does anyone see what the problem could be or what I may be doing wrong?

This is the output when I run `Link.order(cached_votes_up: :desc)`. Even though I downvoted this post, it is still returning the object as containing an upvote?

```
irb(main):001:0> @link = Link.order(cached_votes_up: :desc).first
  Link Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "links".* FROM "links"  ORDER BY "links"."cached_votes_up" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Link id: 16, title: "John F Kennedy", url: "Change is the law of life. And those who look only...", created_at: "2015-12-26 23:56:26", updated_at: "2015-12-26 23:56:31", user_id: nil, cached_votes_total: 1, cached_votes_score: 1, cached_votes_up: 1, cached_votes_down: 0, avatar: "jfk.jpeg">
```

This is my link model containing the acts_as_votable object:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.per_page = 5
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user, presence: true
    acts_as_votable
    attr_accessor :avatar
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

This is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  resources :links do
    member do
      put "like", to: "links#upvote"
      put "dislike", to: "links#downvote"
    end
  end
  root to: "links#index"
```

These are my downvote and upvote actions:

```
  def upvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Comment: check the query issued for Link.order(cached_votes_up: :desc), see if it uses order by created_at, cached_votes_up

Comment: @DileepNandanam went into the console to try that out and it turns out that when I vote down on a link, it is not registering. Instead it continues to have my `cached_votes_up: 1` and `cached_votes_down: 0`, even though I downvoted and then restarted the console session.

Comment: @DileepNandanam I posted what I am seeing in the question

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  def index 
    ordered_links = Link.order(cached_votes_up: :desc)
    @links = ordered_links.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)

    respond_to do |format| 
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Suggestion: change '''@links = Link.order''' to '''ordered_links = Link.order'''. Then change '''@links = @links.paginate''' to '''@links = ordered_links.paginate'''

Comment: I do like this change @MilesStanfield and Yang. I implemented it. It turns out that this may not be the problem I am having, if you take a look at my updated question, my downvotes are not being registered when I change from a downvote to an upvote.

Comment: Can your users vote a link multiple times without overwriting the previous behaviour?

Comment: Can we see ur dislike_link_path and like_link routes and also their corresponding controller actions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say in your comments your actually having problems registering a downvote, this may help you

According to [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/blob/master/README.markdown) gem docs

> By default all votes are positive

So

```
@post.vote_by :voter => @user3
```

Is actually a positive vote. To down vote you need to do something like this ...

```
@post.vote_by :voter => @user4, :vote => 'bad'
```

Or

```
@post.downvote_from @user2
```

Comment: I posted my controller and routes file. Based on what you are explaining here, I think I have that, but just used the `downvote_from`.